# How to create multimatch query in elasticsearch using JAVA API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to create elastic search query using JAVA api but it is adding some extra elements in JSON and also the fields are appending with ^1.0.

Expected JSON QUERY:

```
{
      "from": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                  "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4"
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 2,
                "query": "test",
                "type": "phrase",
                "boost": 5
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                  "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4"
                ],
                "query": "test",
                "type": "phrase",
                "boost": 5
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                  "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4"
                ],
                "operator": "and",
                "query": "test",
                "type": "cross_fields"
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                  "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4"
                ],
                "operator": "or",
                "query": "test",
                "type": "cross_fields"
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "fields": [
                  "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4"
                ],
                "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                "query": "test",
                "type": "best_fields"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "size": 250,
      "sort": [
        {
          "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

output from code :

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "test",
          "fields" : [
            "column1^1.0",
            "column2^1.0",
            "column3^1.0",
            "column4^1.0"
          ],
          "type" : "phrase",
          "operator" : "OR",
          "slop" : 0,
          "prefix_length" : 0,
          "max_expansions" : 50,
          "minimum_should_match" : "2",
          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 5.0
        }
      },
      {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "test",
          "fields" : [
            "column1^1.0",
            "column2^1.0",
            "column3^1.0",
            "column4^1.0"
          ],
          "type" : "phrase",
          "operator" : "OR",
          "slop" : 0,
          "prefix_length" : 0,
          "max_expansions" : 50,
          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 5.0
        }
      },
      {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "test",
          "fields" : [
            "column1^1.0",
            "column2^1.0",
            "column3^1.0",
            "column4^1.0"
          ],
          "type" : "cross_fields",
          "operator" : "AND",
          "slop" : 0,
          "prefix_length" : 0,
          "max_expansions" : 50,
          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "test",
          "fields" : [
            "column1^1.0",
            "column2^1.0",
            "column3^1.0",
            "column4^1.0"
          ],
          "type" : "cross_fields",
          "operator" : "OR",
          "slop" : 0,
          "prefix_length" : 0,
          "max_expansions" : 50,
          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "test",
          "fields" : [
            "column1^1.0",
            "column2^1.0",
            "column3^1.0",
            "column4^1.0"
          ],
          "type" : "best_fields",
          "operator" : "OR",
          "slop" : 0,
          "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
          "prefix_length" : 0,
          "max_expansions" : 50,
          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

JAVA code which I am using is:

```
        String queryString = "test";
        QueryBuilder cluase0 = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryString, 
                "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4").type(Type.PHRASE).boost(5f).minimumShouldMatch("2");


        QueryBuilder clause1 = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryString, 
                "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4").type("phrase").boost(5);







        QueryBuilder clause2 = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryString, 
                "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4").operator(Operator.AND).type("cross_fields");



        QueryBuilder clause3 = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryString, 
                "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4").operator(Operator.OR).type("cross_fields");



        QueryBuilder clause4 = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryString, 
                "column1",
                  "column2",
                  "column3",
                  "column4").fuzziness("AUTO").type("best_fields");





        QueryBuilder combinedBoolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(cluase0).should(clause1).should(clause2).should(clause3).should(clause4);
        System.out.println(combinedBoolQuery);
```

I am not getting what is getting wrong, How I can get the required JSON query by modifyig the Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct, only few changes will make it work.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index-name");
String queryString = "test";
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
// Multimatch query builder 1
MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder1 = new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(queryString, "firstName", "lastName",
      "password", "emailId", "userId", "mobileNumber");
multiMatchQueryBuilder1.operator(Operator.AND);
searchSourceBuilder.query(multiMatchQueryBuilder1);

// Multimatch query builder 2
MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder2 = new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(queryString, "firstName", "lastName",
      "password", "emailId", "userId", "mobileNumber");
multiMatchQueryBuilder1.operator(Operator.OR);
searchSourceBuilder.query(multiMatchQueryBuilder2);

// Multimatch query builder 3
MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder3 = new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(queryString, "firstName", "lastName",
      "password", "emailId", "userId", "mobileNumber").type("cross_fields");
multiMatchQueryBuilder1.operator(Operator.OR);
searchSourceBuilder.query(multiMatchQueryBuilder3);

// Multimatch query builder 4
MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder4 = new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(queryString, "firstName", "lastName",
      "password", "emailId", "userId", "mobileNumber").fuzziness("AUTO").type("best_fields");
multiMatchQueryBuilder1.operator(Operator.OR);
searchSourceBuilder.query(multiMatchQueryBuilder4);

searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = esclient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

1. You need to use the `SearchSourceBuilder` and add your individual querybuilder like  `multiMatchQueryBuilder1`, `multiMatchQueryBuilder2` ,`multiMatchQueryBuilder3` to it, using `searchSourceBuilder.query(multiMatchQueryBuilder2)`.
2. You also need to add `SearchSourceBuilder` to `SearchRequest` object using `searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)` method.
3. ES by default boost every field by a factor of 1, hence you are seeing `^1` with every field in generated ES JSON query, please refer [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html#mapping-boost) in ES for more info.

Comment: How we can disable the boost factor and your code is returning only on query instead of 4.
{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"test","fields":["emailId^1.0","firstName^1.0","lastName^1.0","mobileNumber^1.0","password^1.0","userId^1.0"],"type":"best_fields","operator":"OR","slop":0,"fuzziness":"AUTO","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"boost":1.0}}}

Comment: and also some extra fiels are adding which by default it is adding

Comment: @ashok having boost 1 means no special boost, so no need to disable it, other fields are by default ES client adds, if you print your ES query which you build using ES JHLRC, it will print that time as well

Comment: but for your code if I am printing searchRequest it is giving printing only one query. And also how can I get the query as I asked in the question like type phrase, fields with boost 1. As you can see I want the boost as 5 in first multimatchquery and fields with 1 boost.

Comment: @ashok i provided important constructs and now using them you should be able to construct your exact query  reg printing one query i will check and fix that

Comment: thank you, but I am asking you to check the code once which I have shared regarding phrase,fields,boost those things are already included whether it is correct or not

Comment: Is there any difference between boost method and default boost how this will affect